# How to pass Curl answer to a static text component in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, curl

I'm trying to find the curl in Cartesian Coordinates for a specific equation in which the user's input is typed in a text box using matlab. In CLI, I used the following equation and it worked: `curl([2*x+3*y, 2*y, 2*z], [x, y, z])`

Using the GUI I created (for simplicity) one text box (let's say it's for x coefficient) static text label will show the answer and a push button will trigger my code.

**the text box tag is inputTxt**

**the static text lable tag is inputValue**

The button callback is:

```
txtValue=get(handles.inputTxt, 'String');
set(handles.inputValue, 'String', curl([textValue*x, 0, 0], [x, y, z]));
```

When pushing the button I hear a ding sound which fires an error in matlab cli and nothing appears in the static text label. Even when I set the curl parameters myself just like I did in the CLI first:
`curl([2*x+3*y, 2*y, 2*z], [x, y, z])`
I get the same result (a ding sound) and nothing appears in the label text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried converting the numeric output of `curl` to a string first, e.g using `num2str`?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer and it did work out.

To pass the curl results to static text use

```
char(curl([x^3*y^2*z, y^3*z^2*x, z^3*x^2*y], [x, y, z]));
```

complete code

```
syms x y z;
set(handles.txtAns, 'String', char(curl([x^3*y^2*z, y^3*z^2*x, z^3*x^2*y], [x, y, z])));
```

txtAns is static text lable and it should shows the following answer after clicking a push button (if you placed the above lines in push button callback)

matrix[(x^2*z^3 - 2*x*y^3*z) (x^3*y^2 - 2*x*y*z^3 (-2*x^3*y*z + y^3*z^2)]

Answer (score 0):

mmounirf, can you try changing:

```
txtValue=get(handles.inputTxt, 'String');
set(handles.inputValue, 'String', curl([textValue*x, 0, 0], [x, y, z]));
```

to this:

```
txtValue=str2num(get(handles.inputTxt, 'String'));
set(handles.inputValue, 'String', num2str(curl([txtValue*x, 0, 0], [x, y, z])));
```

Can you also post the error please? Basically you're getting a string from the edit box which you need to convert to a number. Then, when you're setting the text, you need to convert the number you get from `curl` to a string. I also noticed that you changed `txtValue` to `textValue` which will cause errors as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually it didn't work out, as I tried to troubleshoot the code from the very start. All I need now is to get the curl results shown in the static text lable so I just added the callback to the button to set the string property to the results of the curl function.

`syms x y z`
`curlAns = curl([2, 3, 4], [x, y, z]);`
`set(handles.inputValue, 'String', num2str(curlAns));`

Comment: >Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

E>rror in num2str (line 83)
>            xmax = double(max(abs(x(:))));

>Error in test>pushbutton1_Callback (line 106)
>set(handles.inputValue, 'String', num2str(curlAns));

>Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
>        feval(varargin{:});

>Error in test (line 42)
>    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

>Error in >@(hObject,eventdata)test('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,gui>data(hObject))

 
>Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: I dont think you should be using symbolic objects here. I'm assuming from your post the user types in a set of numbers and then the output is also a set of numbers...?

Comment: Yes, this is true, I just wanted to make sure that it will work from the very start, that's why I did try to set it directly without user input in text box however it didn't work. I did use symbolic as the curl function parameters is values in direction of x, y and z

The problem is that I can't return the output of curl function in GUI component, I want to know how to do so

Comment: Thanks @jucestain for everything :) the problem is that the GUI components cannot pass in any mean a symbolic equation I tried to solve something like log(10) and the answer shows in the static text controller however when assigning the static text to show something like diff(x^2) it gives me the same error. I'm trying to find a way to pass symbolic equations to static text controller

Comment: @mmounirf No problem. Look at this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/char.html. The `char` function can convert symbolic objects into strings. This should allow you to display them with edit or text control UIs.